# не получается задать свойство элемента html Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Я изучаю Angular по учебному проекту, проект вроде и 2020, но ни чего не работает. У меня стоит 11 версия, в учебнике используется 9. В учебнике определяется переменная, которая меняет свойство html элемента, при создании задаю начальное значение:

```
menuMode = 'push';
```

а вот тут передаю ее в html

```
<ng-sidebar
    [mode]="menuMode"
>
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"over" | "push" | "slide"'.
```

Если переменную объявить так:

```
menuMode: 'over' | 'push' | 'slide';
```

то компилятор пропускает, но это как-то не правильно, а если завтра появится еще одно свойство

Comment: А так <ng-sidebar [mode]="{{menuMode}}">?

Comment: Вариант с объявление как `'over' | 'push' | 'slide'` мне кажется более правильным, так как у тебя идет проверка в типе, и ты не ошибся в шаблоне и не написал posh вместо push. Так у тебя проверка будет до компиляции, и не нужно будет изобретать проверку на ошибки. А если у тебя появится новое свойство - ничего страшного, они могут добавляться и убавляться - норма разработки. Даже если их у тебя будет штук 10, ничего страшного не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант не true-way - обозначить как `any`

```
menuMode = 'push' as any;
```

Использование `any` очень плохая практика, не рекомендуется к использованию.

Второй вариант - вывести отдельный тип:

```
type MenuMode = 'over' | 'push' | 'slide';
menuMode: MenuMode = 'push'; // соответствует записи menuMode: 'over' | 'push' | 'slide';
```

При использовании `type MenuMode`, если добавится еще одно значение, то нужно будет его добавить только в объявление типа `type MenuMode = 'over' | 'push' | ...;`

Также нужно учитывать, что если изначальный тип не Ваш, а например из библиотеки и вы не можете его получить напрямую через `import`. То Ваш `type MenuMode` должен быть таким же как нужный тип данных или меньше. То есть:

```
Начальный тип 'over' | 'push' | 'slide';
type MenuMode = 'over' | 'push' | 'slide'; // будет работать
type MenuMode2 = 'over' | 'push'; // будет работать
type MenuMode3 = 'over' | 'push' | 'slide' | 'leave' ; // НЕ будет работать
```

Третий вариант - вывести отдельный тип и объявить переменную как тип:

```
type MenuMode = 'over' | 'push' | 'slide';
menuMode = 'over' as MenuMode;
```

Конструкция `as MenuMode` не очень желательна при использовании в коде, может являться причиной багов в runtime.